# Last commit id in submodule that made it into parent commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

How would I get the "last" commit into a submodule that "made it into" a commit of a parent (assuming I create a commit into parent for each commit of submodule) ?

e.g.

Parent repo P

Submodule S

For every commit into S master branch, I create a commit in P master branch.  Now based on commit hash=X of P, how do I find the very last commit into S before that commit?

NOTE: I'd like to do this withing checking timestamps and such.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, because if I do understand it, the answer is entirely trivial.  If P is a superproject that uses S as a submodule, then *every commit in P* (that uses S at all) records the ID to be checked out in S.  That is, if revision IDs were simple counting numbers, and the very first revision in P started with using revision 26 of S, you would see commits in P that say: *I use revision 26 of S* over and over, up until you switched P to start using revision 27.  Then you'd see commits in P saying, over and over, *I use revision 27 of S*, and so on.

So if you want to know which revision of S it is that commit X in P uses, simply look at commit X in P; it tells you (via its tree and subtrees, down to where the [gitlink](https://book.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/1.8.3) is, which in-S commit hash that commit in P calls for.

Comment: Thank you so much. Based on the information in your post, I was able to write figure out the command I need ```git ls-tree commit-in-parent submodule-dir```